# Accessing ASP.NET web application that only runs on a local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

So I have zero experience with deploying software or putting something live. The situation is like this:

I have developed a dashboard web application on a laptop. This application uses a microsoft SQL database that also runs locally. When I run it, it's a localhost address. Now, I need to be able to access my web application from other PCs within my company's network. This way I can do some user testing. What are ways to do this? I searched and things confuse me to no end.

I use:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
- IIS7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you'll need to do to make your local application visible on the network. I'm assuming you want your app running on something like `http://foobar/myapp` where `foobar` is the name of your machine

Here is what you need to do:

1. Add a URL reservation so your machine will allow IIS to serve content on the url `http://foobar/myapp`
2. Create an inbound rule in Windows Firewall to allow incoming connections on port 80

You can find the exact commands you need to run on [Scott Hanselman's excellent blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx). Of course, he's focusing mainly on getting SSL to work with IIS Express, but it has enough pointers to get you going, too.

Answer (score 0):

look at [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
you can learn about:

- Prerequisites
- Creating the Web Site
- Creating a Test Page and Class
- **Publishing the Web Site**
- **Testing the Published Web Site**
- Next Steps